# REST - How in the response we return only fields which we require?

Tags: rest, jersey, resteasy, restful-authentication

I was asked in an interview that you have an API - say `getCustomer`. This API returns details of the customer. But to reduce the size of the REST response, we need to return only the attributes which have value. So if `middleName` is not there for the customer, we should not see `{ middleName=null }` in the response. How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jackson you can exclude null values from JSON serialization in two ways:

- Globally (for all classes) by setting the property **JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL** in the ObjectMapper, as already suggested by ritesh.garg

  ```
  mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
  ```
- At single class level, annotating the class with **@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)** as follows:

  ```
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  public class Customer {

  }
  ```

Here you can find a detailed explanation and code samples: [Jackson: how to exclude null value properties from JSON serialization](http://www.davismol.net/2016/01/08/jackson-how-to-exclude-null-value-properties-from-json-serialization/)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it with your message converter configuration. E.g. in case one is using Jackson Message Converter it can be set using the [serialization inclusion property](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setSerializationInclusion(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include)) of Jackson Object mapper.

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```